# sql convert string to date/datetime

Tags: sql, string, date, sqldatatypes

My Filename column looks like 'D181115.T000000'. I used the following code to make it a string, looks like '2018-11-15'.

```
select '20' + substring(filename, 2,2) + '-' + substring(filename, 4,2) + '-' + substring(filename,6,2)
from table_name
```

Then I want to convert the string to date type (because I need to sort by date)

```
select convert(datetime, '20 + substring(filename, 2,2) + '-' + substring(filename, 4,2) + '-' + substring(filename,6,2)')
from table_name
```

Then I got this error message:

> The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the subtract
>   operator.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Those queries are product specific.)

Comment: You are missing a single quote after `'20`, then it is doing `Substract` operation:`20 + substring(filename, 2,2) + `    minus    `20 + substring(filename, 2,2) + '`

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? In that case you could use just `select cast('20' + substring('D181115.T000000', 2,6) as date)` or `select try_cast('20' + substring('D181115.T000000', 2,6) as date)`. `YYYYMMDD` is a recognized, unambiguous date literal. `YYYY-MM-DD` on the other hand depends on the `DATEFORMAT` setting

Comment: `Then I want to convert the string to date type` <= Look at the first and 2nd statements you included, they are different in that you are missing a lot of quotes in the second one.

Comment: You should be careful with string to date conversions. It is always better to start with date/datetime over a string date. You may never know in what format the string date `181115` was meant to be interpreted as `'2018-11-15'` or `'2018-15-11'`. Just something for thought.

Comment: you will get the correct result if you copy your first query correctly inside the `Convert`, you are just missing a`'` after `'20` in your 2nd query, then if you look carefully, they are doing the string subtraction, which is invalidate operation, which the error gave to you. anyway, "YYYYMMDD" is the universal format, safe to use, upvote @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspet the database is SQL Server. In that case one can use just

```
select cast('20' + substring('D181115.T000000', 2,6) as date)
```

or

```
select try_cast('20' + substring('D181115.T000000', 2,6) as date)
```

`YYYYMMDD` is one of the two unambiguous date formats. The other is the full ISO8601 date+time format. `YYYY-MM-DD` on the other hand depends on the DATEFORMAT setting

*Update*

I'd suggest performing this conversion as part of data loading though. Applying functions to a field prevents the server from using any indexes that cover the field. The server will have to scan the entire table in order to produce the final values used for filtering and sorting.

At least consider addd an indexed computed column that produces the file date

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will use 20181115 as the filename instead.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to convert the string to date type

Look at the first and 2nd statements you included, they are different in that you are missing a quote and you added an extra quote in the second one.

```
declare @filename varchar(20) = 'D181115.T000000'
select convert(datetime, '20' + substring(@filename, 2,2) + '-' + substring(@filename, 4,2) + '-' + substring(@filename,6,2))
```

Produces output:

```
2018-11-15 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: this is because i am following the example SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2017-08-25'); I feel stupid. Thanks for the help!